# calculate average CPI

Tags: cpu-cache, clocks

I cannot solve this exercise:
"If a processor has a cache hit rate of 99.5% and a cache miss penalty of 160 core processor cycles, what will the average CPI be for 1,000 instructions?"
how can i do this?

Comment: This is a question in arithmetic.

Comment: yes can help me calculate this question? which formula?

Comment: It's your job to find out the formula. We're not a service for doing people's homework for them.